# IIS SMTP Relay to Google Apps adds header to e-mail body

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-6, smtp

I have an IIS6 SMTP set up to relay e-mail for applications on my intranet that does not support TLS to a Google Apps e-mail account [per this tutorial](http://www.jppinto.com/2010/07/how-to-configure-iis-smtp-server-to-forward-emails-using-a-gmail-account/).

For the most part it is working great, but when I send an e-mail through the relay the following information is added to the bottom of the message:

```
From: paging@mydomain.org
Return-Path: paging@mydomain.org
Message-ID: <randomString@bpdsrvr2>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 30 May 2011 23:50:51.0503 (UTC) FILETIME=[683D3FF0:01CC1F24]
Date: 30 May 2011 19:50:51 -0400
```

At what point is this information being added? Is it being done by IIS or Gmail?
Is there any way I can get rid of this information?

This relay is intended for senting out text messages and having all of this extra information makes it unusable.

EDIT: I have determined that the problem originated from IIS. I tried using another SMTP relayer (instead of IIS) and the headers did not print in the message body. I still have no idea why IIS would be doing this.

Answer (score 1):

following these instructions on windows 2003 (IIS6):

http://routerjanitor.blogspot.com/2011/08/google-apps-iis-smtp-relay.html

I have exact the same info added, but only in the header.

Tested sending both a gmail account and a normal account.
We do use postini though, so that adds some more to the headers before the message gets delivered.